# Connecting PC with static IP to netbooter

Tags: ethernet, dhcp, static-ip

I am trying to connect a netBooter to a computer with a static IP address. The instructions in the netbooter ( http://www.synaccess-net.com/support.php ) say that I can connect the netbooter directly to my computer via a crossover ethernet, but that my PC must also be on the same subnet of 192.168.1.0... so I am not sure how to rectify this problem as I cannot change the IP address of my computer.

Apparently, the netBooter can also be hooked straight into the LAN using DHCP, but once I do that, I am still not sure how to get the computer to be able to communicate with it.

Here is a link for the pamphlet that comes with the machine: http://synaccess-net.com/downloadDoc/NPStartup-BXXX.pdf

any and all help is greatly appreciated!

*edit - The computer I am trying to hook up to the netbooter is forced into having a static IP address by the group that owns the computer, I am not completely sure why.

Comment: Why are you unable to change the IP address while you configure the device?  If IT policy, talk to support. If not, please add more info

Comment: essentially, we aren't allowed to change the IP addresses for the CPUs when we move them... I am not even sure if changing that computers IP address is something I should even have to do. I am basically completely lost.